# Custom delegate nil and not saving userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I make a delegate inside UIView to passed data to my controller and than I save it in userdefaults. but when I try to save it, it return nil. How can I save it and not return nil.

this is my code in UIView and my protocol

```
protocol SaveUpdateInputDelegate {
   func saveInputText()
   func fetchInputText()
}

class FormUIView: UIView {

var delegate: SaveUpdateInputDelegate?

let nameLabel = ProfileCustomLabel(textName: "Name")
let nameTextField = CustomTextField(placeholderName: "Name")

let emailLabel = ProfileCustomLabel(textName: "Email")
let emailTextField = CustomTextField(placeholderName: "Email")

let titleLabel = ProfileCustomLabel(textName: "Title")
let titleTextField = CustomTextField(placeholderName: "Title")

let locationLabel = ProfileCustomLabel(textName: "Location")
let locationTextField = CustomTextField(placeholderName: "Location")
```

this is my controller code that have a button to save the input text and save it in userdefaults

```
class ProfileController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, SaveUpdateInputDelegate {

// I need to initialized this to create autolayout
let formView: FormUIView = FormUIView()

let saveButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1254901961, green: 0.7411764706, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSave), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formView.delegate = self
    handleSave()
}

@objc func handleSave() {
    print("saved...")
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profileImageEditedKey") as? Data else { return }
    let image = UIImage.init(data: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.profileImageView.image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }

    saveInputText()
    fetchInputText()
}

func saveInputText() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(formView.nameTextField.text!, forKey: "nameTextFieldKey")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(formView.emailTextField.text!, forKey: "emailTextFieldKey")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(formView.titleTextField.text!, forKey: "titleTextFieldKey")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(formView.locationTextField.text!, forKey: "locationTextFieldKey")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func fetchInputText() {
    let name = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "nameTextFieldKey") as? String ?? ""
    let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "emailTextFieldKey") as? String ?? ""
    let title = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "titleTextFieldKey") as? String ?? ""
    let location = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "locationTextFieldKey") as? String ?? ""

    formView.nameTextField.text = name
    formView.emailTextField.text = email
    formView.titleTextField.text = title
    formView.locationTextField.text = location
}
```

Comment: can you put code of calling "saveInputText" function?

Comment: I put it in viewDidLoad @JatinKathrotiya

Comment: If you call `saveInputText()` in viewDidLoad(), surely the textfields are empty and there won't be any saved in UserDefaults

Comment: Can you put more code related to how you called `saveInputText` and `fetchInputText`?

Comment: @Kamran I update my question check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call only `fetchInputText` in `viewDidLoad` just to set the `textFields` text from the `UserDefaults`. Currently you are calling `handleSave` which internally calls `saveInputText` when `textFields` have no values(or default values). It might crash if you haven't put any default `text` in `Storyboard/Xib` for any of these `textFields`.,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formView.delegate = self

    fetchInputText()
}
```

And the purpose of using `delegate` does not look meaningful because the `FormUIView` is not propagating anything for `delegate` to handle. This might be wrong as i don't know the complete implementation of `FormUIView`.

Comment: hey thank you I don't know how but it works :) @Kamran

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using delegate to pass data that is not necessary or you are doing something wrong.

**As all are the textfield so you can directly set textField Delegate to ViewController** So there is no need for passing value around & this is not proper use of delegate here

Suppose you can't do that then you need to call delegate every time when `textFieldShouldChangeCharacter` or `textFieldDidEndEditing` 
 Called but as I said this is wrong way

Step1: Verify all correct information is saved inside

Step 2:   UserDefault has already method to fetch string

Replace this

```
let name = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "nameTextFieldKey") as? String ?? ""
```

with

```
 let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "nameTextFieldKey") ?? ""
```

and others too.

Comment: where the user called the `formView.saveInputText()`  function in class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik That's the requirement of user. Without seeing all scenario it is difficult to tell. However he doesn't need that. As all are textfield he can directly  set delegate  of textfield to viewcontroller

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Edited my answer

Comment: so I only save it in userdefaults once in 'textFieldShouldChangeCharacter'? and retrieve it In that too @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: @ferryawijayanto Could you please let me know What is reason behind this messy structure ?  So I can provide you better solution if I can. What about delegate in ViewController ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I want to make a view which is have a textfield, label, and button. so I want to clean my code to separate what is inside the view and what is inside the controller. since my textfield inside my UIView I need to passed it the information into my controller, I don't know if this is the right method. so that's the reason this structure I made

Comment: @ferryawijayanto Your intension is right no doubt. but method you choose is seems to be problematic in case if your app grows in future. What I suggest you is that it is fine to keep your label & textfield to Uiview Subclass but passing data around makes no sense as Texteild is anyway part of UIViewController and you can directly access with self. like self.yourCusotmView.textfield. Solution would be keep your textField delegate to your view controller like self.yourView.txtField1.delegate = self. so you have more control over data.

Comment: Secondly You need be careful  about when you are saving your text to userdefault so you don't loose anything in any scenario

Answer (score 0):

Call `formView.saveInputText()` should be called from `viewDidAppear()` function instead of `viewDidLoad()` function.